# Using InstallShield 2012 to Install ASP .Net MVC Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, installshield

Does InstallShield 2012 have built-in capabilities to install Web Applications?  This would include configuring IIS, App Pool accounts etc. Does anyone know of any tutorials to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the IIS View (Designer)   It looks alot like the IIS Mgmt Tool and you just go and define all your IIS Objects and attributes.  InstallShield takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The Limited Edition (free) version cannot manage IIS application pools, Web service extensions, etc. The paid versions can. Yet another reason to switch to WiX.