# How to install/require MVC using Installshield

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installshield

I want to be able to check for/install MVC in my InstallShield installScript MSI project. I did see this entry

[Using InstallShield 2012 to Install ASP .Net MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768723/using-installshield-2012-to-install-asp-net-mvc-application)

but the MVC portion was not detailed. I didn't see MVC in the redistributables list.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try just [bin deploying mvc](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)